# How to hide UITabBar on a UITabBarController that I didn't subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

## Visually this is what I want

I have a [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller). I want to hide the [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar) when the user enters the middle tab. The middle tab's loads a view controller of class B. This is the behavior of the popular camera app [Instagram](http://instagr.am/). Their middle tab loads up a full screen camera.

```
-------------    -------------    -------------
|     VC    |    |     VC    |    |     VC    |
|    for    |    |    for    |    |    for    |
|     A     |    |     B     |    |     C     |
|           |    |           |    |           |
|------------    |           |    |------------
{ A } B | C |    |           |    | A | B { C }
-------------    -------------    -------------
```

## Proposed solution from all other related StackExchange questions

We already have dozens of questions on how to hide the UITabBar when a particular view controller is pushed. The general consensus is this:

```
b.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:b
                                     animated:YES];
```

My problem is, I never subclassed the UITabBarController. I created it in Interface Builder. I never manually push my view controllers, so the above solution doesn't work for me.

## Failure attempt 1

Inside my middle view controller, I turn on `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`in the constructor. This had no effect.

```
@implementation B

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

## Failure attempt 2

I also tried assigning my app delegate as a [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate). When the UITabBarController notifies me that a tab has been tapped, I turn on `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` only for the middle view controller. This also failed to hide the `UITabBar`.

```
#pragma mark UIApplicationDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.rootViewController.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[B class]]) {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    } else {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you COULD subclass it and let IB return an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) hidetabbar:(BOOL)hiddenTabBar
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in self.uiTabBarController.view.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {

            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
        } else {
            if (hiddenTabBar) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
            } else {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
    hiddenTabBar = !hiddenTabBar;
}
```

Comment: Where is this code placed? The only place that has access to the UITabBarController object is in my App Delegate. The App Delegate has no view property, which your code tries to use. /// And I kind of figured out how to do it in a cleaner fashion. I do `tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;`, but there's a white space where the tab bar used to be. So I tried to set the frame of the pushed view controller's view to be 320 x 480, but that did nothing. So I read about this hack: `[tabBarController.view addSubview:viewController.view]`, which kind of works. It's getting too hairy.

Comment: You can create a tabBarController ivar in the class X using this code. Then in MainWindow.xib you drop a uiviewcontroller icon, set its class to X, and link the ivar to the UITabBarController. This code should animate down the tabbar. Anyway, it's just one way to do it.